# Java Attribute Driven Collection

Tags: java, collections, attributes, membership

I need to implement some specific functionality and I am wondering if you might know of a java library that does this, or something like it already. I would rather use an existing before building my own.

Basically I want a collection type class that contains instances of *FooBar*. When the container is constructed, I specify the attribute values or ranges that qualify a FooBar for membership, so when a FooBar instance is inserted, it will be rejected if it does not meet the criteria. In addition, if the attributes of any FooBar in the container are modified in such a way that they no longer meet the membership criteria, they will be ejected (preferably with some sort of callback to registered listeners).

I can elaborate more, but I think the concept is fairly straight forward.

Seen anything like that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a set of listeners to the class performing the add / retain and which allows the class to 'choose' whether to add candidate as a listener - and also later on based on your interesting events occurring - whether to 'retain' them or evict them:

```
public interface AddableEvictable {
  public boolean isAddable();
  public boolean evict();
}
```

Then add a Set to your interesting server class and candidate classes to add/(/later evict) would need to (a) implement this simple interface and (b) offer themselves to the server class for it to decide whether to add/not (and later when/if to evict)